# How to pass a parameter to a query using dbExpress in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbexpress, firebird2.5

I want to use a dbExpress TSQLQuery component. But i do not know how to write the SQL to add a parameter. I will give an example maybe it will be more clear what my problem is.

In a TADOQuery the following works:

```
SELECT*
FROM sometable
WHERE sometable.id = :value;
```

Now in the above example you pass the parameter to the query using the colon (:) before the parameter name. But when I try and do that with the TSQLQuery, I get the following error:

```
dbExpress driver does not support the TDBXTypes.UNKNOWN data type. Vendor Error Message.
```

Now if this is not the way that you pass a parameter in a TSQLQuery component, can someone please assist me. This is new territory for me.

Im using a Firebird database, and Im using Delphi XE2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To set the properties of a parameter you must use the [`Params`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.Params) property. From here you can access each paramer using a index or the name, to set the value of the parameter use one of the [properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TParam_Properties) [AsString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TParam.AsString), [AsInteger](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TParam.AsInteger) an so on, depeding of the type of the field.

Check this sample

```
var
  LSQLQuery : TSQLQuery;
begin
  LSQLQuery:=TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    LSQLQuery.SQLConnection:=SQLConnection1;
    LSQLQuery.CommandText:='Select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEE Where EMP_NO=:Param1';
    LSQLQuery.Params.ParamByName('Param1').AsInteger:=2;//or using the index of the parameter LSQLQuery.Params[0].AsInteger:=2; 
    LSQLQuery.Open;//Execute the query
    ShowMessage(LSQLQuery.FieldByName('FIRST_NAME').AsString); //get the data
    LSQLQuery.Close;
  finally
    LSQLQuery.Free;
  end;
end;
```